# How to POST Data to Join Database CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I created a form page that will be sent student profile database's table that have been joined. But some data can't be uploaded to database and reads null. Null legible data is data that has been linked to other tables using id. This is the error massage :

```
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`elsi`.`placement_test`, CONSTRAINT `placement_test_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_teacher`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id_teacher`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

INSERT INTO placement_test (id_student, id_class, date_test, id_teacher, ket, time_e, time_s) VALUES ('', '', '2020-02-26', '', 'dmwkfmw', '13:00', '')
```

This is my model script :

```
public function get_place()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('placement_test');
        $this->db->join('students','students.id_student=placement_test.id_student');    
        $this->db->join('teacher','teacher.id_teacher=placement_test.id_teacher');
        $this->db->join('class','class.id_class=placement_test.id_class');


        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }

public function insert($id_student, $id_class, $date_test, $id_teacher, $ket, $time_e, $time_s)
{
     $hsl=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO placement_test (id_student, id_class, date_test, id_teacher, ket, time_e, time_s) VALUES ('$id_student', '$id_class', '$date_test', '$id_teacher', '$ket', '$time_e', '$time_s')");
    return $hsl;
}
```

This is my controller script :

```
public function add(){
        $name_student = $this->input->post('id_student');
        $class_level = $this->input->post('id_class');
        $date_test = $this->input->post('date_test');
        $name_teacher = $this->input->post('id_teacher');
        $ket = $this->input->post('ket');
        $time_s = $this->input->post('time_s');
        $time_e = $this->input->post('time_e');


    $data = array(
        'id_student' => $name_student,
        'id_class' => $class_level,
        'date_test' => $date_test,
        'id_teacher' => $name_teacher,
        'ket' => $ket,
        'time_s' => $time_s,
        'time_e' => $time_e
        );
    $this->Mplacement_test->insert($name_student, $class_level, $date_test, $name_teacher, $ket, $time_e, $time_s);
    redirect('academic/placement_test');
}
```

And this is my view script :

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/academic/Placement_test/add"> 
                <h3 class="text-center">Tambah Jadwal Placement Test</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Nama Murid</label>
                     <div class="form-group">
                     <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
                    <option value="">Pilih Siswa</option>
                    <?php foreach ($place->result() as $key => $data) { ?>
                        <option value="<?=$data->id_teacher?>"><?=$data->name_student?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                </div>
                </div> 
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Pilihan Kelas</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="class_level" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>Pilih Kelas</option>
                         <?php foreach ($place->result() as $key => $data) { ?>
                            <option value="<?=$data->id_class?>"><?=$data->class_level?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Jadwal Test</label>
                <input type="date" name="date_test" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
               </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="time_start">Waktu Mulai</label>
               <input type="time" name="time_e" class="form-control">
           </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="time_start">Waktu selesai</label>
               <input type="time" name="time_e" class="form-control">
           </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Guru Pendamping</label>
                 <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                <option value="">Pilih Guru</option>
                <?php foreach ($place->result() as $key => $data) { ?>
                    <option value="<?=$data->id_teacher?>"><?=$data->name_teacher?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Catatan</label>
                <textarea name="ket" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
            Add New Placement Test
            </button>
        </form>
```

Is there anything wrong in my script? Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: I don't know if there is an error in your script but in your INSERT-Statement the teacher_id empty. In the error message you can read that the teacher_id is "foreign key", so it must not be empty.

Comment: By the way, why don't you use the [Codeigniter Query Builder](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) for the INSERT-Statement?

Comment: You never debug your POST-Request, did you? Because in your form is no element with an "id_student" name tag, "id_class" name tag or "id_teacher" name tag. And so everytime you call `$this->input->post('id_teacher')` , `$this->input->post('id_class'); ` and `$this->input->post('id_teacher');` it will be empty.